# Spring Security REST-based User Authentication without Boilerplate Code

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have not found a simple one-off config option to secure user sections in a REST URL without doing a lookup everytime using either Spring’s @PreAuthorize annotation or via code. To keep things naturally REST, let’s say there is this URL:

```
colleagues/private/user1/todolist
```

I’m aware in Spring you can configure as follows:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/colleagues/private/**“)
.authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

however, once an authenticated user has access to colleagues/private, there is nothing to stop user1 in:

```
colleagues/private/user1
```

accessing user2’s private area in:

```
colleagues/private/user2
```

and henceforth access say:

```
colleagues/private/user2/todolist
```

etc.

Does anyone know of a better way without verbose taking advantage of Spring Security's latest version config options?  For example, is there a way to configure something like below having just once config for REST-based url security for a user (or any sub-element of the URL) that is only accessed by him/him or by any condition that's configured:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/colleagues/private/{user}/**”)
.access({user}==principal.username]/**“).anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `@PreAuthorize` to your methods that need this check, instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, that is, having @PreAuthorize annotations everywhere, but rather have it in one place having something like:   http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/colleagues/private/{user}/**”).access({user}==principal.username]/**“).anyRequest().permitAll();

Comment: You cannot. As there is no way that the filter knows about the filter that is going to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a `@PreAuthorize` annotation for every controller method.

```java
@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.name")
@RequestMapping("/colleagues/private/{userId}")
public User getUser(@P("userId") @PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You need to repeat for `todolist` and so on, but I still think it is pretty simple.

*Or* you can put the `@PreAuthorize` on your DAO interface and possibly avoid some duplication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, even though it is simple as you said, but I don't want verbose, that is, all those checks everywhere, but rather have them in one place.